# Allowing windows pop up via windows service

Tags: c#, wcf, service, certificate, chilkat

I use a WCF service hosted at windows for digital signature using e-token

e-token forced pop up for username and password which is possible in windows application, but in service, it throws error as it cant able to prompt pop up at 
**"lcWriteBytes = loCryptoTest.OpaqueSignBytes(lcReadByte);"**

Is there any way to allow windows pop up via service

Here is my code:

```
namespace CryptService
{

    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {

        Chilkat.Crypt2 loCryptoTest;
        Chilkat.Cert locertTest = null;

        public Service1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            loCryptoTest = new Chilkat.Crypt2();
            loCryptoTest.UnlockComponent("key for unlocking");
            locertTest = new Chilkat.Cert();
            bool lbsuccess = locertTest.LoadByCommonName("certificate name");

            if ((lbsuccess != true))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failure loading cert");
            }

            loCryptoTest.SetSigningCert(locertTest);
            byte[] lcWriteBytes = null;
            byte[] lcReadByte = loCryptoTest.ReadFile(@"D:\Test\Input.htm");
            lcWriteBytes = loCryptoTest.OpaqueSignBytes(lcReadByte);
            lcReadByte = loCryptoTest.ReadFile(@"D:\Test\Input.htm");
            lcWriteBytes = loCryptoTest.OpaqueSignBytes(lcReadByte);

            if (lcWriteBytes.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Opeque Signature Error");
            }
            loCryptoTest.WriteFile(@"D:\Test\InputCrypt.htm", lcWriteBytes);
            lcReadByte = null;
            lcWriteBytes = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.  Windows service are not the same thing as WCF, and Windows service are not intended to be interactive.  2.  What is the error you get on the line you indicated?

Comment: service cant interact hence it shows in my error log
WindowsError: An internal error occurred.
      WindowsErrorCode: 0x80090020

Comment: they used SafeNet Authentication client for that e-token
is there any option that e-token dont require popup for username and password